# PyQt license explanation

Tags: python, licensing, pyqt

We am developing a free application as a desktop version of our music site. We intend to earn from users subscription later in the future. Do we need to purchase a license for PyQt?

Comment: If free means 'freedom' (Open Source) you don't

Comment: Legal questions about software licenses are off-topic on Stack Overflow, but *may* be on-topic on its [Programmers sister site](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/). Please see [stackoverflow.com/tags/licensing/info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/licensing/info).

Comment: You might be interested in http://www.pyside.org/

Comment: @Daniil its not an open source software.

Answer (score 1):

If your software is released under the GPL, you don't need to buy a license.